# How to change marker icon what it was tapped?

Tags: android, google-maps

In our project we use google maps v2, and I need to find a way to change pin icon after the pin was tapped. Also I need to return initial icon for this pin when another pin will be tapped.
So now we have something like this:

```
public ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<OurClusterItem> mClusterItemClickListener = new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<OurClusterItem>() {

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(OurClusterItem item) {
        // Some actions here
        return true;
    }
};
```

and then we set this listener to map:

```
ClusterManager mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<OurClusterItem>(getActivity(), getMap());
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(mClusterItemClickListener);
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

So, can someone offer solution for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, I found solution for it - maybe this also will helps to someone.

So, at first, we need to use our custom renderer (inherited from `DefaultClusterRenderer`). `DefaultClusterRenderer` has his own cache that contains pairs of `ClusterItem` and corresponding `Marker`:

```
public MarkerCache<T> mMarkerCache = new MarkerCache<T>();
```

so I wrote the next method in our `CustomClusterRenderer`

```
public Marker getMarker(OurClusterItem clusterItem) {
    return mMarkerCache.get(clusterItem);
}
```

After it, I've added to our fragment 2 variables:

```
private Marker mCurrentSelectedMarker;
private ClusterStore mCurrentSelectedClusterItem;
```

and change implementation for `ClusterItemClickListener`:

```
public ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<OurClusterItem> mClusterItemClickListener = new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<OurClusterItem>() {

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(ClusterStore item) {
        // return to previous marker non-selected icon
        if (mCurrentSelectedMarker != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(mCurrentSelectedClusterItem.getIconResourceId()));
        }
        Marker marker = mCustomRenderer.getMarker(item);
        if (marker != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedMarker = marker;
            mCurrentSelectedClusterItem = item;
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(item.getIconSelResourceId()));
        }
        // some other code
        return true;
    }
};
```

That's all, and it works like a charm.

Comment: I didn't use your answer but its gave me a way to solve my problem, thx there

Comment: Thanks dude its working for me. However I didn't use MarkerCache.

Comment: can someone share their solutions?

Comment: there is a method `getMarker(T clusterItem)` in `DefaultClusterRenderer` which returns the marker from a Cluster